# Angular 4 animation on children: style jumps back

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I want to fade out an element's child, by animating its opacity. It's working fine, but **at the end of the animation, the child's style is reverted back to it's original state** (opacity un-set).

How can this be prevented / how can I tell Angular to leave the style in the target state once the animation has completed?

Here's my code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-playground',
  template: `
  <div [@simpleStateTransition]="simpleState">
    {{ simpleState }}
    <div class="fadeout">fade this child out!</div>
  </div>

  <button (click)="toggleSimpleState()">toggle simple state</button>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('simpleStateTransition', [
      transition('initial => extended', group([
        query('.fadeout', animate('300ms', style({'opacity': '0'})))
      ])),
    ])
  ]
})
export class PlaygroundComponent {

  simpleState = 'initial'

  constructor() { }

  toggleSimpleState() {
    this.simpleState = this.simpleState === 'initial' ? 'extended' : 'initial'
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont have much idea on animation but you can try ngAfterViewInit as that is the sage when view render complated. just an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, it's actually much easier than I thought. We don't need to get into the 'query for children and kick off their animation' business at all.

Simply create 2 separate animations, and trigger them from the same expression. Having separate triggers allows us to define start and end styles that persist after the animation is done.

Here is some sample code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('parentAnimation', [
      state('expanded', style(styles.backgroundExtended)),
      state('compact',  style(styles.backgroundCompact)),
      transition('expanded <=> compact', animate(timings.background))
    ]),
    trigger('childAnimation', [
      state('expanded', style(styles.hideExtended)),
      state('compact',  style(styles.hideCompact)),
      transition('expanded <=> compact', animate(timings.background))
    ])
  ]
})

<div [@parentAnimation]="visualState">
    <h1>Hello from parent</h1>
    <div [@childAnimation]="visulaState">
        A Child! 
    </div>
    <div [@childAnimation]="visulaState">
        Another Child! 
    </div>
</div>
```

To me this is much nice / cleaner / easier solution. Please leave a comment if you see any drawbacks.

Comment: @M98 I think you mean stagger.

Comment: Yes. Excuse my typo